# Java Switch Case with multiple inputs

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to do a *tamagotchi*, and I would like it to be possible for the object to recieve more than one command from the same scanner. So when I type "sleep", that afterwards I can write in the console the next thing that it should do like "eat".

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tamagotchi blue = new Tamagotchi("Lenns", 8, 4, 6, 7);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Input = scanner.nextLine();

    switch (Input) {
    case "Eat":
        blue.eat();
        break;

    case "Sleep":
        blue.sleep();
        break;

    case "Sport":
        blue.sport();
        break;

    case "Condition":
        blue.output();
        break;

    default: System.out.println("no valid option");
        break;
    }
```

I hope you understand my question and can help me.
Thank you very much for your precious time.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: I write my first command and after this i cant write the second so after i write sleep the programm is "over"

Comment: Put your code into a `while` loop.

Comment: You need to put your code in a while loop if you want to be able to enter multiple inputs. A switch case only executes one time. After that one time it exits.

Comment: ok thank you could you show me how you would do it im not quit shure how do implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small tweak to the answer above

```
String Input = null;
while(true){
    try{
         Input = scanner.nextLine();
         switch (Input) {
            case "Eat":
                blue.eat();
                break;
            case "Sleep":
                blue.sleep();
                break;
            case "Sport":
                blue.sport();
                break;
            case "Condition":
                blue.output();
                break;
            default: 
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operation");
        }
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }     
}
```

If u use this variation, u need to add a "quit" case or similar to be able to break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For repeating a segment of code you need a loop, in your case, wrap the reading of the user input and the switch-case so the actions can be repeated

```
String Input = null;

while(true){
    Input = scanner.nextLine();
    switch (Input) {
    case "Eat":
        blue.eat();
        break;

    case "Sleep":
        blue.sleep();
        break;

    case "Sport":
        blue.sport();
        break;

    case "Condition":
        blue.output();
        break;

    default: System.out.println("no valid option");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank is kinda works put its loops the same command all the time i want to write a diffrent command afterwards

Comment: @brianmichelson You need to put the `nextLine` inside the loop, as shown above.